# Error when calling tq_get function of the tidyquant package for dividend data of Yahoo Finance (when some symbols have no dividend data)

Tags: r, tidyverse, yahoo-finance, tidyquant

My code:

```
pacman::p_load("tidyverse","tidyquant")
setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path))
'%&%' <- function(a,b) paste(a,b)

Stocks<-c("MSFT","IWDA.AS")
D  <- tq_get(Stocks, get = "dividends", from = " 2010-01-01",complete_cases = TRUE)
```

The error:

```
Error in `dplyr::mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `data.. = purrr::map(...)`.
Caused by error in `purrr::map()`:
ℹ In index: 2.
Caused by error in `dimnames<-.xts`:
! 'dimnames' applied to non-array
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

The problem is that IWDA.AS has no dividend data and I get an error on that i guess.
(I have actually a longer list of symbols with a few with symbols with no dividend data, not possible to eliminate them and here I give a reduced list.)

The same code worked fine 2 years ago, so I don't know what changed, something with tidyquant or yahoo finance?

Is there a quick fix for this?

(Same error occurs with 'get = "splits"'.)

Comment: Just set `complete_cases = FALSE`. It will ignore the stocks without dividends. You will get no error.

Comment: If use: 
D  <- tq_get(Stocks, get = "dividends", from = " 2010-01-01", complete_cases = FALSE)


I get the same error, so it doesn't help.

Comment: Have you updated tidyquant and quantmod? Because I can't replicate your error and everything works on my side.

Comment: I have an updated version of R (4.3.0) & tidyquant 1.0.7, strange... 
I use now as a not so nice workaround a for-loop & "quantmod::getDividends"
Thank you!